# Python ZipFile is zipping part of the text files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a simple script that will take arguments and then run commands based on those arguments. For the output of each command it saves it into a file and then at the end it zips up the files. It makes the files with the full output of the command in it, but then when it zips the files it doesn't put the whole file in it. It captures the first line and then that is all. The first file goes in without a problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import subprocess
from zipfile import ZipFile

filenames = []

def zip():
with ZipFile('zippity.zip', 'w') as zip:
    for file in filenames:
        zip.write(file)


def command(cmd, arg, banner, filename, i):
    ban = '------------' + banner + '-------------\n'
    if i.islower():
        filenames.append(filename)
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        f.write(ban)
        if arg == '':
            subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=f)
        else:
            subprocess.Popen([cmd, arg], stdout=f)
        f.close()
    elif i.isupper():
        filenames.append(filename)
        print '------------' + banner + '-------------'
        os.system(cmd)
        print('\n')
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        f.write(ban)
        if arg == '':
            subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=f)
        else:
            subprocess.Popen([cmd, arg], stdout=f)
        f.close()


def menu():
    print('System Survey v1.0\n' +
          'Usage: ' + sys.argv[0] + ' [OPTIONS]\n' +
          'Example: ' + sys.argv[0] + ' -a -i -r -b\n' +
          'Description: Lowercase will create file and not display to screen. \n' +
          'Uppercase will display and save to file.\n\n' +
          '----[OPTIONS]----\n' +
          '-i         ifconfig -a\n' +
          '-r         route\n' +
          '-w         whoami\n')


for i in sys.argv:
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        menu()
        break
    if i == '--help':
        menu()
        break
    elif i == '-i' or i == '-I':
        command('ifconfig', '-a', 'IFCONFIG', 'ifconfig.txt', i)
    elif i == '-r' or i == '-R':
        command('route', '', 'ROUTE', 'route.txt', i)
    elif i == '-w' or i == '-W':
        command('whoami', '', 'WHOAMI', 'whoami.txt', i)
    elif i == sys.argv[0]:
        continue
    else:
        print(sys.argv[0] + ': option not recognized.')
        print(sys.argv[0] + ': --help gives usage information.')

zip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `Popen` object you create, you must call the `wait` method on it so that the process completes before you start zipping up the file.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = f)
process.wait()
```

Comment: Awesome, that helped but now that banner "------------banner-----------" is printing at the bottom of each output.

Comment: That sounds like a different question.